Mass of boron in boric acid
I have recently submitted a slime activator product for EN71-3 UK toy safety testing. The test aims to measure the amount of boron that is able to migrate from the toy if it is consumed by a child in its liquid form. The results surprised me as they, according to my limited knowledge, appear to show more boron migrating than existed to begin with. Are my assumptions incorrect, are the results incorrect or is there some other explanation?

Mass of water - 100g
Mass of boric acid - 0.5g
Mass of boron detected in testing - 0.1275g

ICP-MS is used to measure the boron content

I think it is clear enough. How much B is there in 0.5 g of H3BO3, really?

yes, pretty much that @IvanNeretin

Are you sure the starting material has this formula, H3BO3? What did you add, is there a CAS number and certificate of analysis of your boric acid? To your question, the mass of boron is around 0.087 gram. The result is higher.

It was described in the online store as H3BO3, CAS number 10043-35-3, however I have no easy way of confirming what was supplied is what it was supposed to be. Thank you for confirming the mass of boron present.

As you state, the mass of boron in true boric acid is ~1/6 the mass of H3BO3. Therefore, either the test is in error, or you were sold  boron trioxide,  "boric acid anhydride", instead. Read the product label carefully, and have it analyzed to see which it might be.

Your CAS number is correct for boric acid. Actually, as an analytical chemistry, ICP results without standard deviation is meaningless for us.

There is no mention of standard deviation. The results do mention a "measurement uncertainty" of +/- 19% and an MDL for boron of 10mg / kg total material

Update: I submitted the same samples to another test provider. The results from this new lab were much more in line with my expectations and the figures quoted in these comments.
